# how to short long url in <a href="" .......?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, url, href

iam getting in my view sometime very long urls like this:

```
"https://www.google.de/#hl=de&sclient=psy-ab&q=break+long+url+css&oq=break+long+url+&gs_l=serp.1.1.0i30l4.3822.3822.0.5634.1.1.0.0.0.0.85.85.1.1.0...0.0...1c.Hao7HfzLitY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=48c9a29cac04fd97&biw=1680&bih=925"
```

it very anoying because takes a lot of place.

i want to give out in my view just short version of it like -> `"https://www.google.de/#hl=de&sclient=psy-"`

but i will click it, then landing again on this one which contains full path.

how can i  do it with html a href="" link???

Comment: Could you put the full example link into your question, and then show, explicitly, what you'd like it to become? And are you wanting to shorten what's in the `href` and create a 'short URL' (as with [tinyurl](http://www.tinyurl.com/), or do you want to show the `href` in the *text*, but only show a shortened version of that `href`?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here - how to use an anchor tag? The contents of the tag and the `href` don't have to match, if that's the question.

Comment: Can you explain where the URL comes from and how it gets onto the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<a href="full-url">short-url</a>
```

The short url will be displayed on the page, but the link will point to the full url.

Comment: hahaha, so easy!! sometimes my head is full of sawdust! it is greate, thank you. it will be the best joke of august!!! hahaha

Comment: Was not sure if that's what the OP was asking at first, looks like the comment confirms it.

Comment: @Spudley, how did you think of that?!?! @Oded, same here, I thought for sure he wanted to incorporate a URL shortener. Wouldn't have guessed this. @RagimsRagimovs, happens to the best of us, but made me laugh none the less (mostly because I was writing a detailed description on how to use the Bit.ly API) just remember that a MVC view is HTML and any HTML code works. (And the `@Html.xxx` just renders more complex HTML, without you needing to type it all out, for example if you view the source of the page you can see what `@Html.TextBox` or whatever `@Html` code you use renders.

Answer (score 1):

Use a URL Shortener, Google has one with an Api you can connect to

http://goo.gl/

https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started

Answer (score 1):

you can display long text url to short using CSS Properties
try out this one...

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: inline-block;
max-width: 40%;
```